# Alias for set of commands?

Tags: c#, alias

I dont really know how to ask this as i have no idea how to do this. let me explain this in code:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static int alias ()
    {
        set;
        of;
        commands;

    }
    private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     exec alias
    }

}
```

What i want to do it define a set of commands under "alias" and have button1 execute alias

Comment: with commands i mean "messagebox.show"and such

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are expecting:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static int alias ()
    {
       //your commands comes here
    }
    private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       alias(); //this will invoke your alias function
    }

}
```

If you are looking for code instead of comments in commands section in alias() then specify what exactly you want to do here

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call the method:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = alias();
}
```

Side note: No need for the method to be static as you're using it inside an instance:

```
public static int alias ()
{
    //set;
    //of;
    //commands;
}
```

Comment: but how do i make the method?

Comment: @JoepvanDiessen what do you want this method to do ?

Comment: i want it to fill in a box on a site. i have multiple options wich you can select. so when the button is clicked it checks what is checked on form1 and executes the code that belongs to the checked boxes

Comment: @JoepvanDiessen do you know how to use the `if` statement ?

Comment: @JoepvanDiessen write whatever command you want inside the block of the method `alias`